# Where can I learn more about lesser known mathematicians?

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request, education

I'm reaching the point in my mathematical career that the names aren't so well known. Everybody knows that Euler was great and Gauss was even better, and it's not hard to learn that if Riemann died too young, then Abel died when he was only 26.

Anyway, there's a lot of things named after a lot of people, and my education just feels incomplete without knowing who these people are and what they were up to. Is there such a thing as an anthology or maybe a good MOOC I can look at in my spare time?

Comment: Hi, jdoe, welcome to HSM. As it stands, this seems a bit broad, because you appear to be asking about every mathematician who has ever had something named after him/her - and there are a *lot* of those. Would you like to restrict it to perhaps one mathematician? You'll also want to narrow down just what you want to know - there are plenty of fantastic biographies about all of these people out there.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [large list of links to biographies here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/BiogIndex.html). Most mathematicians on the list are not as well known as Gauss and Euler, and they link to MacTutor, which is more reliable than Wikipedia.

Comment: Hi, anon, welcome to HSM! This answer is quite short; could you explain why the site is good, for those who have not visited? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the aforementioned site is not that good... For instance, if you follow the link which I add below, you will find a couple of lies that every wannabe historian brings up when he or she is told to talk about the life and miracles of the great Kronecker: http://www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Quotations/Kronecker.html